# How to handle String lists in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have two tables as follow:
Let's say tbl1(Which keeps the main applicant info) and tbl2(the main applicant with family members info, note that we must keep the main applicant here too)

[image: Table structure here]
I'm trying to check whether the main applicant added oneself to tbl2 or not (that means if main applicant info is in tbl2)

```
CID  FullName
-----------------------
1001 AYNALEM A NIGUSSIE
```

while in tbl2 (Same CID as tbl1):

```
HID   CID   FullName
-------------------------------------
 1    1001  AYNALEM A NIGUSSIE
 2    1001  CARLSTON HEITH
 3    1001  Q LEE
```

I declared a variable to hold FullName list from tbl2 and compare the full name from tbl1 (to check if it exists in tbl2, function [dbo].[ufn_GetFullName] is used to get fullName from tbl1 ).

```
DECLARE @HH_FullName VARCHAR(250);

SELECT 
    @HH_FullName = (SELECT 
                        STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ DR.FullName 
                               FROM 
                                   (SELECT DR.HID, DR.FullName 
                                    FROM dbo.tbl1 DR WITH(NOLOCK)                                       
                                    WHERE DR.CID = PC.CID) DR 
                               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')) 
                    FROM [dbo].[tbl2] PC WITH (NOLOCK)
                    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tbl1] HC WITH (NOLOCK) ON HC.CID = PC.CID 
                    WHERE PC.CID = 100037

/*              --SELECT @HH_FullName --  'AYNALEM A NIGUSSIE', 'CARLSTON 
HEITH', 'Q LEE'
SELECT 
    (STUFF((SELECT ',''' + Val+''''
            FROM 
                (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(250), value) AS Val 
                 FROM string_split(@HH_FullName, ',')) DF
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''))  -- 'AYNALEM A NIGUSSIE',' CARLSTON HEITH',' Q LEE'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(250), value) AS Val 
FROM string_split(@HH_FullName, ',')
    */
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[tbl1] PC WITH(NOLOCK) 
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tbl2] HC WITH(NOLOCK) ON HC.ClaimantID = PC.ClaimantID
   WHERE HC.CID IS NOT NULL 
      AND ([dbo].[ufn_GetFullName](Pc.FirstName, Pc.MiddleName, Pc.LastName)   
NOT IN ( SELECT ( STUFF((
            SELECT ',''' + Val+''''
            FROM (SELECT convert(VARCHAR(250), value)  AS Val FROM string_split(@HH_FullName, ','))DF
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')) ))
```

-- OR as follow

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tbl1] PC WITH(NOLOCK) 
                LEFT JOIN  [dbo].[tbl2] HC WITH(NOLOCK) ON 
HC.CID = PC.CID
                WHERE HC.CID IS NOT NULL AND 
                ( [dbo].[ufn_GetFullName] 
   (Pc.FirstName,Pc.MiddleName,Pc.LastName)  NOT IN (SELECT convert(VARCHAR(250), value) 
as VAL FROM string_split(@HH_FullName, ',') ) )
```

-- Also tried this way, it won't work either

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tbl1] PC WITH(NOLOCK) 
                LEFT JOIN  [dbo].[tbl2] HC WITH(NOLOCK) ON 
HC.CID = PC.CID
                WHERE HC.CID IS NOT NULL AND 
                ( [dbo].[ufn_GetFullName] 
   (Pc.FirstName,Pc.MiddleName,Pc.LastName)  NOT IN ( @HH_FullName  )
```

WHERE Cond NOT IN (@HH_FullName) not returning the right value.

Comment: What is the question? And can you share some details? Like the table structure of the tables in your query, the functions etc...

Comment: I have to be missing something; your SQL is way more complicated than should be needed based on what you say the tables contain. This doesn't work? select tbl1.fullname, CASE WHEN tbl2.fullname IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS [Exists in TBL2] from tbl1 left join tbl2 on tbl1.fullname = tbl2.fullname

Comment: @SeanLange can you go over the question again, I've re-edited to make it clear.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean please revisit the question, and unflag it, I tried to make it more clear this time.

Comment: @Kenneth_pro_ What's wrong with Isaac's answer below? Join concatening table 1's name fields to table 2's fullname. The problem is still not clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

Like @UnhandledExcepSean commented you are complicating this beyond your stated objective...

> I want to check if the FullName in tbl1 also exists in tbl2.

This statement will do it...

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl1 AS t1
INNER JOIN tbl2 AS t2 
    ON CONCAT_WS(' ', t1.FirstName, t1.MiddleNAme, t1.LastName) = t2.FullName
```

This would work too...

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl1 as t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tbl2 
    WHERE FullName = CONCAT_WS(' ', t1.FirstName, t1.MiddleNAme, t1.LastName))
```

Another way...

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl1 as t1
WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', t1.FirstName, t1.MiddleNAme, t1.LastName)
    IN (SELECT FullName FROM tbl2)
```

You will have to account for the case where there is no middle name. Is it NULL or just an empty string? Or perhaps even spaces?

For small volumes of data you are not going to be able to detect a difference in performance. However, for larger amounts of data I believe you will be better off with the [EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) approach.

Comment: please find the table structure updated.

Comment: So tbl1 does not have a FullName column even though you say "To make it clear, in tbl1 one I have data like:" and list FullName? Hmm. I'll revise my answer.